# import net.sf.jasperreports.view; import net.sf.jasperreports.engine; how to get this jar files

Tags: java

I am the beginner of creating jasper reports. i don't know to get this namespaces please some help me for this.import net.sf.jasperreports.view; import net.sf.jasperreports.engine;when i click the button report show on the jframe.
i attached the image  below.

[image: r]

[image]

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.view;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine;

  String report = "C:\\Users\\kobinath\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\payroll\\src\\report1.jrxml";
```

**report1.jrxml**

Comment: add the `jasperreports-x.x.x.jar` file into the project's classpath (x.x.x is a version of the jasper report)

Comment: sir i am new to jsperreport

Comment: how to set the classpath  to jespereport

Comment: which IDE you used

Comment: NetBeans sir ......please tell me the full jar file tell the way step by step please